# Managing routing while extending a controller

Tags: symfony

I am trying to override a controller that I use in Frontend:

```
AcmeDemoBundle:DemoController       //route is /demo
```

For the backend, I extended this controller in AdminDemoBundle:

```
AdminDemoBundle:DemoController      //route is /admin/demo
```

I haven't overriden any methods in the new controller yet, but all the routes from AcmeDemoController go to /admin/demo.

**Does anyone know why?**

Is there a solution to override frontend controllers for backend purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, by extending the controller, all the routes are redefined with the same name and a different prefix, which means that the routes are being replaced.

There is actually no point at all in extending a controller for the backend, as controllers are meant to be tiny. The logic of the app must be kept in services instead.

Moving the logic to a service allows a better organisation of the code. There is no need to worry about backend/frontend when talking about services. Just, create the logic in a service, and use the methods in either a frontend controller or a backend controller.